# SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter + JdbcMetadataStore not pushing values in INT_METADATA_STORE

Tags: spring-integration-ftp

I am writting sftp-integration-ftp inbound flow code to read file from FTP server and want to ensure that if multiple instances of my service and reading file from same input location then only one process the file from the input directory to avoid duplication.

Code :
'''
@Bean
public SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter getSftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(final ConcurrentMetadataStore concurrentMetadataStore) {
return new SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(
concurrentMetadataStore,"INT_");
}

```
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentMetadataStore getConcurrentMetadataStore() {
        return new JdbcMetadataStore(jdbcTemplate);
    }
    
    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "sftpISLChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "30000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "-1"))
    public MessageSource<InputStream> sftpISLMessageSource(final SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter sftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter) {
        ChainFileListFilter<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> chainFileListFilter = new ChainFileListFilter<>();
        chainFileListFilter.addFilter(getCustomOutboundFilter());
        chainFileListFilter.addFilter(sftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter);
        SftpStreamingMessageSource source = new SftpStreamingMessageSource(sftpRemoteFileTemplate, null);
        source.setRemoteDirectory(properties.getInputDir());
        //source.setFilter(getChainFileListFilter());
        source.setFilter(chainFileListFilter);
        return source;
    }
```

```
I'm using oracle DB.

So my questions are 
do I need to create the tables myself for JdbcMetadataStore ?

select * from INT_CHANNEL_MESSAGE;
select * from INT_GROUP_TO_MESSAGE;
select * from INT_LOCK;
select * from INT_MESSAGE;
select * from INT_MESSAGE_GROUP;
select * from INT_METADATA_STORE

Above Queries return 0 records
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved issue

Issue with my local db config